# Mac os snow leopard (10.6) can't connect to any smb fileshare. Connection Fails permission to access denied

Tags: mac-osx, permissions, mac, server-message-block

Mac os snow leopard (10.6) can't connect to ANY smb (windows/linux) fileshares.
Other macs can connect just fine, so I know the problem is machine specific.

Go->Connect to server... select the volumes you want to mount step fails with:
"You do not have permission to access the server."

username/password are correct. The command line tools also fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a permission problem. Use disk utility to repair permissions on disk.

Or manually check /Volumes it should be set to: 
sudo chmod 1777 /Volumes/

On mac os x, especially snow leopard connecting to linux/bsd/windows servers this gets changed to 755 somehow. Of course smb client connecting can break in other ways.

- hudlee